# How would I include the numbers and letters in this diagram

Tags: diagrams, underbrace, overbrace

[image]

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|-|] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[|-|] (5,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

however, this is as far as my limited Tikz knowledge has been able to get me. I had initially hoped to include underbraces between the two sections as well, but that was also an exercise in futility it seems.

Comment: Have you had a look a the Tikz userguide? And commands like `\draw[|-|] (5,0)node[anchor=north] {$1/2$} -- (10,0)node[anchor=north] {$1$};`?

Comment: no, i have been looking mostly at some similar questions and trying to tweak the code to see if it would work for me. Where might I find this?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: many thanks, having a look at it now

Comment: The manual is 1318 pages so you may need a lockdown or two to read the whole thing :D

Comment: http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8]
\draw[-][draw=red, very thick] (0,0) -- (.5,0);
\draw[-][draw=green, very thick] (.5,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (0,-.1) node[below]{0} -- (0,0.1);
\draw [thick] (0.5,-.1) node[below]{$1/2$} -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw [thick] (0.5,-.1) node[above]{$L,R$} -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw [thick] (1,-.1) node[below]{1} -- (1,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```